# fread error with DJGPP

Tags: c++, c, file-io, djgpp

While reading a binary file using DJGPP on DOS this code hangs. 
This happens when the fread call is made. If the call is removed then the program runs successfully. 
The same code runs fine through Visual C++ 2008. 
Has anyone experienced similar issues with djgpp ? 
Am I missing out on something really simple ?

```
char x; 
string Filename = "my.bin" ; 
fp = fopen(Filename.c_str(),"rb"); 

if (fp == NULL)
{
    cout << "File not found" << endl ; 
}

if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_END) != 0)
{
    cout <<"End of File can't be seeked"; 
    return -1; 
}

if ( (fileLength = ftell(fp)) == -1)
{
    cout <<"Can't read current position of file"; 
    return -1; 
}

if (fseek (fp, 0, SEEK_SET) != 0)
{
    cout <<"Beginning of File can't be seeked"; 
    return -1; 
} 

if (fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,fp) != sizeof(x))
{
    cout <<"file not read correctly"; 
    return -1; 
}
```

Comment: fread's first argument should surely be &x and not just x. It wants a pointer to a char buffer, you give it just a char.

Comment: Yes, i fixed that. I still get a hang.

Comment: note: you don't error when the file is not found (a point of style, as such)

Comment: Is there something about the file that might not be well behaved on DOS, such as it's larger than 2GB or 4GB (I'm honestly not sure if DOS has a problem with that or not)?

Comment: how do you know it hangs at the read? (add some cout's to show what's happening)

Comment: +1 to Neil Butterworth... why is it that so often the code posted is not the code that produces the problem? All modern systems have copy-n-paste capability after all.

Comment: @kevindtimm : yes you are right should do throw the error. It hangs on the read because when the read is not there the program runs just fine. 

@Michael Burr: The file size is around 42K, should be OK with DOS

Comment: Time to break out the big guns:  http://www.delorie.com/djgpp/v2faq/faq12_1.html

Comment: Can you try with a larger buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- I don't see what 'fp' is. I just have to assume it's 'FILE * fp;'.
- I don't see that you actually include < stdio.h >, and have to assume you do.
- I don't see that you actually include < iostream > and declare 'using namespace std;', and have to assume you do.
- I don't see what comes after the fread() call that could tell you if call succeeded.

Going through the process of actually reducing your faulty code to the absolute but complete minimum to reproduce the error is the first thing you *should* do when a piece of code has you dumbfounded.

It might (and usually does) turn out that the problem isn't even where you thought it is.

That being said, I'd try replacing

```
if (fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,fp) != sizeof(x))
{
    cout <<"file not read correctly"; 
    return -1; 
}
```

with

```
int i;
if ( ( i = fgetc( fp ) ) == EOF )
{
    perror( "File not read correctly" );
    return -1;
}
x = (char) i;
cout << "Success, read '" << x << "'." << endl;
```

Using 'perror()' instead of homebrewn cout messages gives you additional information on the cause of any error. Using 'fgetc()' will show you that the file actually does contain what you think it does, and that your problems are not due to the somewhat uncommon use of fread() for a single byte.

Then report back.

Comment: @DevSolar The problem arose because of something i was doing much prior to this code - switching off some firmware, causing fread() to fail. Your pointed in the right direction though -- "the problem isn't even where you thought it is."

Answer (score 0):

[fread](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread.html) takes a pointer as the first parameter. If you only have to read in one character, `char x;` is fine, but pass the address of x instead.

```
fread(&x,sizeof(x),1,fp) != sizeof(x)
```

and since sizeof char is always 1 (by definition) you can very well write:

```
fread(&x,1,1,fp) != 1
```

Comment: fixed that still receive a hang.